# C++ how to split code into multiple files?

Tags: c++

I want to split my big program into multiply files... 
maybe one with the struct only,
then the function to read in a csv file and extract the words and put them into an array..
then the other function to sort the array with bubblesort,
and finally the main function where I put everything together...
the thing is just, I declared necessary variables in the beginning of the main function, when I want to separate the functions, the variables that I declared in the main function and that I used for those functions are not found anymore... do I have to pass them as parameters to the functions again? OR is there another /better method ? can I declare extern or static variables?

secondly, I dont know when to make a .h file or another .cpp file and if another .cpp file, it is not allowed to have another main function right, how do I do then? Declare a public class ?

here is my code that I want to separate:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
//#include "studentStruct.h"

using namespace std;    


struct Stud{
        long matrnr;
        char vorname[30];
        char name[30];
        char datum[30];
        float note;
    };


void bubbleSort(Stud mystud[], int studentCounter);             


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   

    const int MAX = 30;
    Stud stud;  
    Stud mystud[30]; // <<-- Array of "Stud" type
    //memset((void*)mystud,0,sizeof(mystud) * sizeof(Stud));
    int wordCounter(0);
    int i(0); //thats the charCounter or index
    int studentCounter(0);
    char wort[MAX];



  FILE * pFile;
  int cnr(0);     

  pFile=fopen("studentendaten.txt","r");  
  if (pFile==nullptr) 
  {
      perror ("Fehler beim öffnen der Datei");
  }

  else
  {       
    while (cnr != EOF) 
    {       
        (cnr=fgetc(pFile)) ;    

        if ((char)cnr == '\n') {
            mystud[studentCounter] = stud;
            studentCounter++;                       
            continue;           
        }

        if ((char)cnr == ';') { 


            wort[i] = '\0'; 

            switch (wordCounter % 5) {

                case 0:             
                stud.matrnr = atol(wort);
                break;

                case 1:
                strcpy(stud.name, wort);
                break;

                case 2:
                strcpy(stud.vorname, wort);
                break;

                case 3:
                strcpy(stud.datum,wort);
                break;

                case 4:
                stud.note = atof(wort); 
                break;
            }           

            wordCounter++;          
            i = 0;
            continue;
        }

        wort[i] = (char)cnr;
        i++;                

    }   

    mystud[studentCounter] = stud;
    fclose (pFile);
}


    bubbleSort(mystud , studentCounter);

    for (int i(0) ; i <= studentCounter; i++) {
    //cout <<mystud[i].matrnr << "  |  " << mystud[i].name << " |  " << mystud[i].vorname <<"  |  " 
    //<< mystud[i].datum <<"  |  " << mystud[i].note << endl;
    printf("%ld %15s    %15s    %15s    %6.1f\n",mystud[i].matrnr,mystud[i].name,mystud[i].vorname,mystud[i].datum,mystud[i].note);  
    }

    return 0;
}

void bubbleSort(Stud mystud[], int studentCounter) {
    Stud tmp;   
    for (int i = 0 ; i<= studentCounter; ++i) {
        for (int j=0; j<= studentCounter-1;  ++j) {
            if (mystud[j].note > mystud[j+1].note) 
            {
                /**
                tmp = mystud[j+1];
                mystud[j+1] = mystud[j];
                mystud[j] = tmp;
                **/

                    tmp.matrnr = mystud[j+1].matrnr;
                    strcpy(tmp.vorname,mystud[j+1].vorname);
                    strcpy(tmp.name,mystud[j+1].name);
                    strcpy(tmp.datum , mystud[j+1].datum);
                    tmp.note = mystud[j+1].note;

                    mystud[j+1].matrnr = mystud[j].matrnr;
                    strcpy(mystud[j+1].vorname ,mystud[j].vorname);                 
                    strcpy(mystud[j+1].name , mystud[j].name);
                    strcpy(mystud[j+1].datum ,mystud[j].datum);
                    mystud[j+1].note = mystud[j].note;

                    mystud[j].matrnr = tmp.matrnr;
                    strcpy(mystud[j].vorname , tmp.vorname);
                    strcpy(mystud[j].name , tmp.name);
                    strcpy(mystud[j].datum , tmp.datum);
                    mystud[j].note = tmp.note;


                }           
            }
        }       
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The best (and standard) thing to do would probably be to:

1. write a class Stud, not a struct (private members of the class would be `name`, `vorname` etc.)
2. make a header file, where you would write the definition of the class with prototypes of all the functions
3. define those functions in a separate .cpp file
4. and finally, you would just make another .cpp file for the implementation (main).

Of course, you need to include your header file in the .cpp files.

Answer (score 0):

- A header files says - We can do this.
- A .cpp file says - This is how we do it - ie. compile it to an object.

The .cpp files use header files to know what is available.

Compile the .cpp files. Generate object files. Link them together and that will do the tie up the loose ends. Bang - Got an executable.